# Understanding the variadic operators

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

I am creating a parser in bison and I have to specify the precedence and associativity of the following binary and variadic operator.

Associativity :Left
Arity: Binary/variadic
Fixity: Postfix
operators: expression[expression], expression.i, function(......)

The problem is that I don't know how these operators relate to associativity and precedence. Can someone give me an example of how this come into play?

For example if I have the rule

```
.
.
.
%precedence HIGHEST
%%
expr : expr '(' expr ')' %prec HIGHEST
%%
```

Then everything in the form expr '(' expr ')' will have the highest precedence?

Comment: `A + B.C` as an example: `(A + B).C` != `A + (B.C)` is that, what you were missing?

Comment: Yes, almost. What about the variadic operator?

Comment: ,....................

Comment: I suggest editing in a complete example of a grammar where you don't know how to resolve associativity/precedence. I.e. `expr : expr '(' expr (, expr)* ')' | expr: expr ',' expr` (I'm not familiar with bison, my usual approach is to LR-ify: `expr : expr ',' no_comma_expr | expr '(' no_comma_expr (',' no_comma_expr)* ')' | no_comma_expr`...)